# SQL Updating with CASE, LAG and SEQUENCE

Tags: oracle, case, sequence, lag

I have a problem with updating of my table. Problem is: I have a table, that contains value and show_order columns (and some more else columns). So, those show_order in table are going one by one, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... and so on. Sometimes those show_order repeats i.e. ... 7, 8, 9, 9, 10 ... 
I need to: make a gap among each show_order in 10 or more points, i.e. 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ... Moreover, if some show_order is repeating then new show_order have to be repeated too, i.e. 70, 80, 90, 90, 100 ...
I try do that:

```
UPDATE
      list_values
    SET show_order = CASE 
                         WHEN show_order = LAG(show_order,1, show_order) OVER (ORDER BY show_order)
                          THEN LAG(show_order,1, show_order + 10) OVER (ORDER BY show_order) + show_order_incr.currval - 10
                          ELSE show_order + show_order_incr.nextval
                     END
    WHERE attr_id = 13;
```

SQL Error: ORA-30483:Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query.
           And, window function cannot be an argument to another window or group
           function.

Does anyone has some ideas how I can do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Might as well create a procedure, so you can save the calculated show_order (through a select) in a variable, and then use that variable to perform the update. ps: buf if you really want to perform everything in the update clause, that case needs a select (as the error suggests). something like: set show_order = (select case .....)

Comment: Where does the sequence fit in to your example old and new values? Can you show some clearer sample data and expected result for that data? At the moment it looks like you're really multiplying the old value by 10...

Comment: Please add expected result matching your data. From what you have written so far, it follows that it is enough to multiply the value by ten.

Comment: See also [Update previous days count using LAG function in ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661293/update-previous-days-count-using-lag-function-in-oracle)