# Update previous days count using LAG function in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I have a table with columns as product, txn_date and no_of_txns. One more column prev_day_txn added recently to the column. Data is something like below:

```
Product   TXN_DATE  NO_OF_TXNS 

AA         1-JAN-19      100
AA         2-JAN-19      180
AA         3-JAN-19      290
```

With the new column added, data in the column should be populated with previous day's data. Output should be something like below:

```
Product       TXN_DATE     NO_OF_TXNS  PREV_DAY_TXN

    AA         1-JAN-19      100          0
    AA         2-JAN-19      180         100
    AA         3-JAN-19      290         180
```

I am trying to update the data using lag function, but getting error `SQL Error: ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here`Same query is working fine in select clause. This is what I tried:

```
update PRD_DTLS set PREV_DAY_TXN = LAG(NO_OF_TXNS, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY PRODUCT, TXN_DATE);
```

Can someone help me with the query. Thanks.

Comment: What a bad idea! Why would you store values in a new column, which can be calculated on the fly from the other columns? Instead of that, if you often need to reference the previous day's data, you should do that in a **view**, and select from the view instead of the table whenever you need to. And if "performance" is your reason, use a **materialized view** instead. Consider: Can you break eggs with a hammer? Of course you can. Should you? ........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MERGE:

```
MERGE INTO PRD_DTLS A USING 
(
  SELECT
      PRODUCT,
      TXN_DATE,
      LAG(NO_OF_TXNS) OVER(
          PARTITION BY PRODUCT
          ORDER BY
              TXN_DATE
      ) AS PREV_TXN
  FROM
      PRD_DTLS 
)
B ON ( A.PRODUCT = B.PRODUCT
       AND A.TXN_DATE = B.TXN_DATE )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.PREV_DAY_TXN = CASE
    WHEN B.PREV_TXN IS NOT NULL THEN B.PREV_TXN
    ELSE 0
END;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a subquery:

```
UPDATE PRD_DTLS pd
    SET PREV_DAY_TXN = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(NO_OF_TXNS) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY TXN_DATE DESC), 0)
                        FROM PRD_DTLS pd2
                        WHERE pd2.PRODUCT = pd.PRODUCT AND
                              pd2.TXN_DATE < pd.TXN_DATE
                       );
```